# Nutanix VM template options

Tags: virtual-machine

I have been given access to the Nutanix prism console to manage the state of the VMs,etc. I see there is a VM template available and when choosing the option to Create VM from Catalog Item don't see the boot configuration option I intend to see.

Is there a possibility I can maintain the boot configuration options in the VM template i.e. Legacy Bios or UEFI Bios mode when creating the VM.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

With our Nutanix clusters, we use Terraform.

Nutanix is a [partner](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/nutanix/nutanix/latest).